# Current activity not found. Make sure to call this method while your application is in foreground

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Using expo-splash-screen and SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() throws many errors in production builds and running app on expo go.

I call preventAutoHideAsync first thing in App.js. The warning message is Current activity not found. Make sure to call this method while your application is in foreground.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20502

Implement as per https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/sdk/splash-screen/
Reproducible demo: https://github.com/kirtikapadiya/SplashReactNative

Comment: I'm really hoping for a neat solution to this problem.

Comment: didn't get any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I have the same problem and are gonna try:

```js
// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync().catch((error) => {
  // Attach the event to error handling system (Sentry, LogRocket etc.)

  // Try to call it again when app state is 'active'
  let attempts = 0
  const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState === 'active' && attempts < 0) {
      attemps++
      SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
        .then(() => appStateListener.remove())
        .catch((error) => {
          // Attach the event to error handling system (Sentry, LogRocket etc.)
        })
    }
    if (attempts >= 3) {
      appStateListener.remove()
    }
  })
})


export default function App() {
  ....
```